# Setting up a Django server with Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I've followed [this](https://medium.com/@_christopher/deploying-my-django-app-to-a-real-server-part-ii-f0c277c338f4) tutorial and i'm running into an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` that i just can't figure out.
I must mention that i have set inside `settings.py`:

`DEBUG = FAlSE`

`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False`

And my Allowed_hosts is `['*']`.

I have a number of questions which reading alot of blog posts hasn't answered:

1. In the `nginx` configuration, if i'm running the server from a laptop connected to a router, and the external IP is 12.34.56.78 and the port is 50000, what am i supposed to put at `server_name`?
2. In the `gunicorn` configuration, everyone states that this is the config command: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8800 AWESOME.wsgi:application` what IP should i put there in my case? `12.34.56.78:50000` or just leave it like it is?

As i understand the situation, given the setting in django `settings.py` my server is not serving HTTPS so the error does not come from that. I've also read about `certbot` but since i don't have even those 2 above questions figured out i cannot understand how to configure certbot..

> EDIT

In fact i've tried to:
`gunicorn --bind 12.34.56.78:50000 KYng.wsgi:application` but i'm getting invalid address error

Answer (score 0):

1.) You actually don't need to put anything in there, as it will default to an empty string.

2.) You should put localhost (*127.0.0.1*) if you want it to run **locally**, or *0.0.0.0* if you want it to run **publicly**.

Concerning the ssl error, check your nginx configuration more closely...that you didn't reference **https** instead of **http** somewhere...